# Jersey api return 415 unsupported media type when using MULTIPART_FORM_DATA

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, grizzly

In server start multipart feature is registered:

```
public static HttpServer startServer() {

    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.server.rest");

    rc.register(MultiPartFeature.class);

    return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
}
```

Simple test POST api:

```
@POST
@Path("/user-picture")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String uploadFile(FormDataMultiPart data) {


    return "OK";

}
```

Server response:

> 415 unsupported media type

To test server I use Mozilla firefox Poster pluging. Other funcions without multipart work ok.

[image]

I tested with diferent content type like images with same result.

Jersey version is 2.17

pom.xml multipart dependency:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Full pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jersey-service</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.server.rest.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.17</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different client that knows how to specifically send files as multipart. You generally don't want to manually create the request (or set the Content-Type header) when it comes to multipart as the it is a little more complicated than a normal request. For example, this a what a multipart request looks like

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit-name"

Larry
--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="file1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

... contents of file1.txt ...
--AaB03x--
```

[See more a W3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)

One client you can use is [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). Or if you are going to automate the test (in an integration test, you can use the [Jersey client support for multipart](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e8856)

Answer (score 0):

The POST method handler is annotated with `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)`.

So, to be mapped to it your request should contain content of the same type. Check that your request header contains

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

Also, I'm not sure about the method argument you use.

Comment: That's not going to work. You normally don't set the header manually when using multipart because you also need to include a boundary in the headers and also in the body. Normally this will will be generated with whatever client you are using. If you just dis what you suggest, you will get a 400 Bad Request